# Is it possible to modify a df from pandas function read_html before pasting into a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to pull a df reading from html function in pandas but for some reason I am not able to modify its columns even so if I select the table I want since its pulling all the tables so you reference the one you want.But when it comes to changing the name of the columns or a specific piece of data from it even just printing a column, I can't figure it out. Anybody out there know's how to deal with this.
Here is a example:

```
import pandas as pd

url= 'http://www.espnfc.com/barclays-premier-league/23/table'

df = pd.read_html(url)
print(df)
print(df[0].Home) '✔ it works
print(df[0][Unnamed: 17]) 'throw's me a error
df.rename(columns = {'Away':'Awayy2'}, inplace = True) 'throw's me a error
```

Comment: What are the thrown errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[0]['Unnamed: 17']
df[0].rename(columns = {'Away':'Awayy2'}, inplace = True)
```

Above works to me. (Apostrophe & [0] missed)

Comment: haha it just needed to reference the column as well and a typo error xD haha I guess I build up on errors...everybody rocks in this comunity thank you guys 4 the support I tried out and it works great...